# Transmit a small XML serialized object via querystring

Tags: c#, xml

I have a small object containing three or so data items that I want to serialize and send in a querystring in order to obfuscate the querystring. The page is opened from a web browser control in a desktop application so using the querystring seems to be the best option.

I could use the System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode method but I suspect that that would be too obvious to a user.

How can I encode the XML serialized object so that it appears as a gaggle of letters and numbers with no illegal characters?

e.g. `<foo><bar>url_goes_here</bar></foo>` becomes `lskjfgdf98gsjkhgdf786sg987dfkjlnadfg89`

Comment: Do you need it to be secure or just not plainly readable?  If secure, encrypt it.  If not readable, base 64 encode it.

Comment: @zimdanen Will either of those methods, regardless of input, produce characters in the encoded string that are invalid or misinterpreted in a url? That's why I was asking

Comment: You'll still need to UrlEncode them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode function is in a VB.NET desktop application:

```
Dim plaintext as String = myState.Serialize
Dim bytes As Byte() = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plaintext)
Dim encrypted As Byte() = Encryption.Encrypt(bytes, key)
Dim encodedtext As String = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted)
Return System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(encodedtext)
```

Decode function is in a C# ASP.NET website:

```
byte[] decodedtext = Convert.FromBase64String(querystring);
byte[] decrypted = Encryption.Decrypt(decodedtext, key);
string plaintext = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypted);
State mystate = new State();
mystate.Deserialize(plaintext);
return mystate;
```